# daterangepicker with datatable search functionality is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm having problem with jQuery DataTables search functionality. 
search functionality is not working this my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
//DATATABLE
//To display datatable without search and page length select, and to still have pagination work, instantiate like so
var oTable=$('#table_id').dataTable({
 
 //"sDom":"tp",
 "pageLength": 10,
 "pagination":true,
  // Date Sorting
 columnDefs: [
       { type: 'date-eu', targets: 1}
     ],
  //// order table onload
"order": [[ 1, 'desc' ]],
 });
//DATE RANGE
//set global vars that are set by daterange picker, to be used by datatable
var startdate;
var enddate;
//instantiate datepicker and choose your format of the dates
$('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
        ranges: {
           "Aujourd'hui": [moment(), moment()],
           'Hier': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
           'Les 7 derniers jours': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
           'Les 30 derniers jours': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
           'Ce mois-ci': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
           'Le mois dernier': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
        }
,
    "opens": "right",
 format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'

},
function(start, end,label) {
// Parse it to a moment
var s = moment(start.toISOString());
var e = moment(end.toISOString());
startdate = s.format("YYYY-MM-DD");
enddate = e.format("YYYY-MM-DD");
});
//Filter the datatable on the datepicker apply event
$('#reportrange').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
startdate=picker.startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
enddate=picker.endDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
console.log(startdate);
oTable.fnDraw();
});

$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
function( oSettings, aData, iDataIndex ) {
if(startdate!=undefined){
// 0 here is the column where my dates are.
//Convert to YYYY-MM-DD format from DD/MM/YYYY
var coldate = aData[1].split("/");
var d = new Date(coldate[2], coldate[1]-1 , coldate[0]);
var date = moment(d.toISOString());
date =    date.format("YYYY-MM-DD");

//Remove hyphens from dates
dateMin=startdate.replace(/-/g, "");
dateMax=enddate.replace(/-/g, "");
date=date.replace(/-/g, "");

//console.log(dateMin, dateMax, date);

// run through cases to filter results
if ( dateMin == "" && date <= dateMax){
return true;
}
else if ( dateMin =="" && date <= dateMax ){
return true;
}
else if ( dateMin <= date && "" == dateMax ){
return true;
}
else if ( dateMin <= date && date <= dateMax ){
return true;
}

// all failed
return false;
}
}
);


} );
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<label class="col-sm-12 col-md-12"></label>
</div>
 <div class="row">
  <label class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
  <form class="form-horizontal">
   <fieldset>
    <div class="control-group">
     <div class="controls">
      <div class="input-prepend input-group"> <span class="add-on input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
       <input type="text" style="width: 200px" name="reportrange" id="reportrange" class="form-control" value="">
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </fieldset>
  </form>
  </label>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
 <div class="table-responsive">
   <table id="table_id" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<thead class="filters">
     <tr>
      <th>Stat.</th>
      <th class="FilterinputSearch">creation</th>
      <th>Col1</th>
      <th class="FilterinputSearch">Col2</th>
      <th class="FilterinputSearch">col3</th>
      <th class="FilterinputSearch">Col4</th>
      <th class="FilterinputSearch">Col5</th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     <tr>
      <td>Approved</td>
      <td>08/08/2015</td>
      <td title="Nouveau Contrat">nv. ctr.</td>
      <td>Donnée 1</td>
      <td>Donnée 1</td>
      <td>Donnée 1</td>
      <td>Donnée 1</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Rejected</td>
      <td>15/08/2015</td>
      <td>prlg. smpl.</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>XTLE<span style="display: none;">New Customer</span></td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Approved</td>
      <td>02/10/2015</td>
      <td title="Nouveau contrat">nv. ctr.<span style="display: none;">Nouveau contrat</span></td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>To be reviewed</td>
      <td>15/11/2015</td>
      <td title="Prolongation simple">prlg. smpl.</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Approved</td>
      <td>22/10/2015</td>
      <td title="Prolongation simple">prlg. nv. ctr.</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Approved</td>
      <td>08/08/2015</td>
      <td title="Nouveau contrat">nv. ctr.</td>
      <td>Donnée 1</td>
      <td>Donnée 1</td>
      <td>Donnée 1</td>
      <td>Donnée 1</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Rejected</td>
      <td>15/08/2015</td>
      <td title="Prolongation simple">prlg. smpl.</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Approved</td>
      <td>16/11/2015</td>
      <td title="Nouveau contrat">nv. ctr.</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>To be reviewed</td>
      <td>15/10/2015</td>
      <td title="Prolongation simple">prlg. smpl.</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Approved</td>
      <td>22/10/2015</td>
      <td title="Prolongation simple">prlg. nv. ctr.</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Approved </td>
      <td>08/08/2015</td>
      <td title="Nouveau contrat">nv. ctr.</td>
      <td>Donnée 1</td>
      <td>Donnée 1</td>
      <td>Donnée 1</td>
      <td>Donnée 1</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Rejected</td>
      <td>15/08/2015</td>
      <td title="Prolongation simple">prlg. smpl.</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Approved</td>
      <td>02/10/2015</td>
      <td title="Nouveau contrat">nv. ctr.</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>To be reviewed</td>
      <td>15/10/2015</td>
      <td title="Prolongation simple">prlg. smpl.</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Approved</td>
      <td>22/10/2015</td>
      <td title="Prolongation simple">prlg. nv. ctr.</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Approved </td>
      <td>08/08/2015</td>
      <td title="Nouveau contrat">nv. ctr.</td>
      <td>Donnée 1</td>
      <td>Donnée 1</td>
      <td>Donnée 1</td>
      <td>Donnée 1</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Rejected</td>
      <td>15/08/2015</td>
      <td title="Prolongation simple">prlg. smpl.</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Approved</td>
      <td>02/10/2015</td>
      <td title="Nouveau contrat">nv. ctr.</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>To be reviewed</td>
      <td>15/10/2015</td>
      <td title="Prolongation simple">prlg. smpl.</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Approved</td>
      <td>22/10/2015</td>
      <td title="Prolongation simple">prlg. nv. ctr.</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Approved </td>
      <td>08/08/2015</td>
      <td title="Nouveau contrat">nv. ctr.</td>
      <td>Donnée 1</td>
      <td>Donnée 1</td>
      <td>Donnée 1</td>
      <td>Donnée 1</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Rejected</td>
      <td>15/08/2015</td>
      <td title="Prolongation simple">prlg. smpl.</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Approved</td>
      <td>02/10/2015</td>
      <td title="Nouveau contrat">nv. ctr.</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>To be reviewed</td>
      <td>15/10/2015</td>
      <td title="Prolongation simple">prlg. smpl.</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Approved</td>
      <td>22/10/2015</td>
      <td title="Prolongation simple">prlg. nv. ctr.</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Approved </td>
      <td>08/08/2015</td>
      <td title="Nouveau contrat">nv. ctr.</td>
      <td>Donnée 1</td>
      <td>Donnée 1</td>
      <td>Donnée 1</td>
      <td>Donnée 1</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Rejected</td>
      <td>15/08/2015</td>
      <td title="Prolongation simple">prlg. smpl.</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Approved</td>
      <td>02/10/2015</td>
      <td title="Nouveau contrat">nv. ctr.</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>To be reviewed</td>
      <td>15/10/2015</td>
      <td title="Prolongation simple">prlg. smpl.</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Approved</td>
      <td>22/10/2015</td>
      <td title="Prolongation simple">prlg. nv. ctr.</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Approved </td>
      <td>08/08/2015</td>
      <td title="Nouveau contrat">nv. ctr.</td>
      <td>Donnée 1</td>
      <td>Donnée 1</td>
      <td>Donnée 1</td>
      <td>Donnée 1</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Rejected</td>
      <td>15/08/2015</td>
      <td title="Prolongation simple">prlg. smpl.</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Approved</td>
      <td>02/10/2015</td>
      <td title="Nouveau contrat">nv. ctr.</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>To be reviewed</td>
      <td>15/10/2015</td>
      <td title="Prolongation simple">prlg. smpl.</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Approved</td>
      <td>22/10/2015</td>
      <td title="Prolongation simple">prlg. nv. ctr.</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Approved </td>
      <td>08/08/2015</td>
      <td title="Nouveau contrat">nv. ctr.</td>
      <td>Donnée 1</td>
      <td>Donnée 1</td>
      <td>Donnée 1</td>
      <td>Donnée 1</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Rejected</td>
      <td>15/08/2015</td>
      <td title="Prolongation simple">prlg. smpl.</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Approved</td>
      <td>02/10/2015</td>
      <td title="Nouveau contrat">nv. ctr.</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>To be reviewed</td>
      <td>15/10/2015</td>
      <td title="Prolongation simple">prlg. smpl.</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Approved</td>
      <td>22/10/2015</td>
      <td title="Prolongation simple">prlg. nv. ctr.</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Approved </td>
      <td>08/08/2015</td>
      <td title="Nouveau contrat">nv. ctr.</td>
      <td>Donnée 1</td>
      <td>Donnée 1</td>
      <td>Donnée 1</td>
      <td>Donnée 1</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Rejected</td>
      <td>15/08/2015</td>
      <td title="Prolongation simple">prlg. smpl.</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Approved</td>
      <td>02/10/2015</td>
      <td title="Nouveau contrat">nv. ctr.</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>To be reviewed</td>
      <td>15/10/2015</td>
      <td title="Prolongation simple">prlg. smpl.</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Approved</td>
      <td>22/10/2015</td>
      <td title="Prolongation simple">prlg. nv. ctr.</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Approved </td>
      <td>08/08/2015</td>
      <td title="Nouveau contrat">nv. ctr.</td>
      <td>Donnée 1</td>
      <td>Donnée 1</td>
      <td>Donnée 1</td>
      <td>Donnée 1</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Rejected</td>
      <td>15/08/2015</td>
      <td title="Prolongation simple">prlg. smpl.</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Approved</td>
      <td>02/10/2015</td>
      <td title="Nouveau contrat">nv. ctr.</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>To be reviewed</td>
      <td>15/10/2015</td>
      <td title="Prolongation simple">prlg. smpl.</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Approved</td>
      <td>22/10/2015</td>
      <td title="Prolongation simple">prlg. nv. ctr.</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Approved </td>
      <td>08/08/2015</td>
      <td title="Nouveau contrat">nv. ctr.</td>
      <td>Donnée 1</td>
      <td>Donnée 1</td>
      <td>Donnée 1</td>
      <td>Donnée 1</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Rejected</td>
      <td>15/08/2015</td>
      <td title="Prolongation simple">prlg. smpl.</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Approved</td>
      <td>02/10/2015</td>
      <td title="Nouveau contrat">nv. ctr.</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>To be reviewed</td>
      <td>15/10/2015</td>
      <td title="Prolongation simple">prlg. smpl.</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Approved</td>
      <td>22/10/2015</td>
      <td title="Prolongation simple">prlg. nv. ctr.</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Approved </td>
      <td>08/08/2015</td>
      <td title="Nouveau contrat">nv. ctr.</td>
      <td>Donnée 1</td>
      <td>Donnée 1</td>
      <td>Donnée 1</td>
      <td>Donnée 1</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Rejected</td>
      <td>15/08/2015</td>
      <td title="Prolongation simple">prlg. smpl.</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Approved</td>
      <td>02/10/2015</td>
      <td title="Nouveau contrat">nv. ctr.</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>To be reviewed</td>
      <td>15/10/2015</td>
      <td title="Prolongation simple">prlg. smpl.</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Approved</td>
      <td>22/10/2015</td>
      <td title="Prolongation simple">prlg. nv. ctr.</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Approved </td>
      <td>08/08/2015</td>
      <td title="Nouveau contrat">nv. ctr.</td>
      <td>Donnée 1</td>
      <td>Donnée 1</td>
      <td>Donnée 1</td>
      <td>Donnée 1</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Rejected</td>
      <td>15/08/2015</td>
      <td title="Prolongation simple">prlg. smpl.</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Approved</td>
      <td>02/10/2015</td>
      <td title="Nouveau contrat">nv. ctr.</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>To be reviewed</td>
      <td>15/10/2015</td>
      <td title="Prolongation simple">prlg. smpl.</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Approved</td>
      <td>22/10/2015</td>
      <td title="Prolongation simple">prlg. nv. ctr.</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Approved </td>
      <td>08/08/2015</td>
      <td title="Nouveau contrat">nv. ctr.</td>
      <td>Donnée 1</td>
      <td>Donnée 1</td>
      <td>Donnée 1</td>
      <td>Donnée 1</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Rejected</td>
      <td>15/08/2015</td>
      <td title="Prolongation simple">prlg. smpl.</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Approved</td>
      <td>02/10/2015</td>
      <td title="Nouveau contrat">nv. ctr.</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>To be reviewed</td>
      <td>15/10/2015</td>
      <td title="Prolongation simple">prlg. smpl.</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Approved</td>
      <td>22/10/2015</td>
      <td title="Prolongation simple">prlg. nv. ctr.</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Approved </td>
      <td>08/08/2015</td>
      <td title="Nouveau contrat">nv. ctr.</td>
      <td>Donnée 1</td>
      <td>Donnée 1</td>
      <td>Donnée 1</td>
      <td>Donnée 1</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Rejected</td>
      <td>15/08/2015</td>
      <td title="Prolongation simple">prlg. smpl.</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Approved</td>
      <td>02/10/2015</td>
      <td title="Nouveau contrat">nv. ctr.</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>To be reviewed</td>
      <td>15/10/2015</td>
      <td title="Prolongation simple">prlg. smpl.</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Approved</td>
      <td>22/10/2015</td>
      <td title="Prolongation simple">prlg. nv. ctr.</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Approved </td>
      <td>08/08/2015</td>
      <td title="Nouveau contrat">nv. ctr.</td>
      <td>Donnée 1</td>
      <td>Donnée 1</td>
      <td>Donnée 1</td>
      <td>Donnée 1</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Rejected</td>
      <td>15/08/2015</td>
      <td title="Prolongation simple">prlg. smpl.</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Approved</td>
      <td>02/10/2015</td>
      <td title="Nouveau contrat">nv. ctr.</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>To be reviewed</td>
      <td>15/10/2015</td>
      <td title="Prolongation simple">prlg. smpl.</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Approved</td>
      <td>22/10/2015</td>
      <td title="Prolongation simple">prlg. nv. ctr.</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
      <td>Donnée 2</td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add relevant parts of code from jsfiddle to question body.

Comment: _Nobody_ will go through that much code without being paid a decent amount.

Answer (score 0):

### html and php code

```
        <table id="example" class="display table table-striped table-bordered " cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Owner ID</th>
                    <th>Type</th>
                    <th>State</th>
                    <th>City</th>
                    <th>Locality</th>
                    <th>Min Price</th>
                    <th>Max Price</th>
                    <th>Created Date</th>
                    <th>Actions</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                       <th>Owner ID</th>
                    <th>Type</th>
                    <th>State</th>
                    <th>City</th>
                    <th>Locality</th>
                    <th>Min Price</th>
                    <th>Max Price</th>
                    <th>Created Date</th>
                    <th>Actions</th>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
            <tbody>

                <?php if($projectsdate){ foreach($projectsdate as $pjdata)
                {  $date = $pjdata['created']; ?>

                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $pjdata['ownerid'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $pjdata['propertytype'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $pjdata['States']['statename']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $pjdata['Cities']['cityname'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $pjdata['locality'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $pjdata['minprice'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $pjdata['maxprice'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php  if($date){ echo date_format($date,"d-m-Y"); } ?></td>
                    <td>Approve</td>
                </tr>

                <?php }} ?>


            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Jquery code
-----------------

$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
function( oSettings, aData, iDataIndex ) {
var iFini = document.getElementById('mindate').value;
var iFfin = document.getElementById('maxdate').value;
var iStartDateCol = 7;
var iEndDateCol = 7;

iFini=iFini.substring(6,10) + iFini.substring(3,5)+ iFini.substring(0,2);
iFfin=iFfin.substring(6,10) + iFfin.substring(3,5)+ iFfin.substring(0,2);


var datofini=aData[iStartDateCol].substring(6,10) + aData[iStartDateCol].substring(3,5)+ aData[iStartDateCol].substring(0,2);
var datoffin=aData[iEndDateCol].substring(6,10) + aData[iEndDateCol].substring(3,5)+ aData[iEndDateCol].substring(0,2);

if ( iFini === "" && iFfin === "" )
{
return true;
}
else if ( iFini <= datofini && iFfin === "")
{
return true;
}
else if ( iFfin >= datoffin && iFini === "")
{
return true;
}
else if (iFini <= datofini && iFfin >= datoffin)
{
return true;
}
return false;
}
);
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
format: "dd-mm-yyyy"
}); 

});

$(document).ready(function() {
var table = $('#example').DataTable();


// Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
$('#example tfoot th').each( function () {
var title = $(this).text();
$(this).html( '<input type="text" class="footer" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
} );

table.columns().every( function () {
var that = this;

$( 'input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
that
.search( this.value )
.draw();
}
} );
} );


} );
```